# Making a string that contains an escaped quote

Tags: c++, string, escaping

I need to make a string that will output exactly `"\""` to the terminal if fed into `std::cout`
I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to do this (c++)

Comment: @0x499602D2 although it was a little unclear, take a look at David's answer. I believe this is what the OP wanted.

Comment: @0x499602D2 No he didn't, he created a string with a quote in it, not an escaped quote (i.e. a backslash and a quote).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply precede each character that needs to be escaped (in your case, all four of them) with a backslash. For instance, this worked for me:

```
std::cout << "Testing: \"\\\"\"" << std::endl;
```

> Output: Testing: "\""

Apparently (I just learned this), [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#New_string_literals) provides other (perhaps better) tools for using string literals. The above method of preceding individual characters with a backslash describes the more old-fashioned way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks for the accepted answer! Many people don't even bother doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string foobar("\"foobar\"");
std::cout << foobar << std::endl;  // Prints "foobar" (with quotes)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Not sure if this works in c++* but in *python* there is a thing called a raw string that ignores escapes and the like. It looks like:

```
r"some stuff\not a \new line"
```

or like:

```
R"some stuff\not a \new line"
```

hope that helped!

Comment: It's actually `R"(…)"`

Comment: @chris either works just one may be more formal not sure which though.

Comment: Mine is the only C++ method. As far as I knew, only `r"…"` worked in Python.

Comment: @chris oh ok. I don't know much C++

Comment: I didn't even realize that C++ provided other support for string literals until seeing this answer/comment section. Thanks for the information!